# Classification of non-hyperbolic equilibrium and its global manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = x^2\\
\dot{y} = -y\\
\dot{z} = z
\end{cases}
$$

Classify the type of equilibrium for the point $(0,0,0)$ when $u=0$ as well as its stability. Also, describe the global stable and unstable manifolds of $(0,0,0)$.

**My attempt:** We easily see that $(0,0,0)$ is not a hyperbolic equilibrium, so we cannot apply either Principle of Linearized Stability or Global Stable/Unstable manifold theorem. However, we also see that the explicit solution for this problem is $(x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (\frac{-1}{t+c_1}, c_2e^{-t}, c_3e^t)$. The global stable manifold is defined as the set of $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} (x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (0,0,0)$. This means $c_3 = 0$ is the only choice, while $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be anything. Thus, the global stable manifold are the entire $xy$-plane. Similarly, for the global unstable manifold, $\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty} (x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (0,0,0)$. This occurs only if $c_2 = 0$. Thus, the unstable manifold is the entire $xz$-plane.

**My question:** Is my solution above correct? Also, is the above method the only way to classify the type of equilibrium for NON-HYPERBOLIC equilibrium in a planar system, assume that we can solve explicitly the general formula for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: You  are  missing some constants, don't you?

Comment: @Pragabhava: I omitted it on purpose, since we don't know what the initial condition is... Doest it matter to the type of equilibrium, and its stability though?

Comment: Where did you get those definitions? It seems that they were given for the hyperbolic equilibria. The only problem with your solution is that it doesn't take into account stable/unstable/center eigenspaces: stable/unstable/center manifold should be tangent to the respective eigenspace.

Comment: @Evgeny: you're absolutely correct about the non-hyperbolic:( My mistake...I don't really know how to do this problem then. Can you help post your solution please?

Comment: As a first step, can you compute the limit of $x(t)$ when $t\to\infty$, depending on $x(0)=x_0$?

Comment: @Did: sure. But does it imply anything about the stable/unstable global manifold? Why only w.r.t $x(t)$ but not $y(t)$ or $z(t)$ though?

Comment: Sorry, "Can you compute blabla?" is euphemism for "Please compute blabla and show the result you get for blabla if you want people to believe you actually worked, even minimally, on the problem before asking for a full solution here".

Comment: @Did: So the limit is $0$ as $x(t)= \frac{-1}{t+c_1}$. My apology, but I actually care more about the general approach rather than mechanism. Unless it's absolutely essential, which is why I did present my work above. Hope you can help more.

Comment: So, you think that the solution of $\dot x=x^2$ starting from some $x(0)>0$ converges to $0$? Please think harder about this case.

Comment: @Did: If $x(0) > 0$, $c_1=-1/x_0$, so $x(t)=-1/(t-1/x_0)$. This approaches $0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. I don't see where i made the mistake here:(

Comment: The computational way: what would be $x(t)$ at time $t=1/x_0$? The conceptual way: what is the phase diagram of the differential equation $\dot x=x^2$ and what does it say about the asymptotics of the solutions $x(t)$ when $t$ grows? (By the way, "when $t\to\infty$" in my first comment should read "when $t$ grows".)

Comment: @Did: vertical asymptote at $t=1/x_0$. $x(t)$ would change from positive to negative at $1/x_0$ and increases to $0$ as $t$ grows.

Comment: No. The solution $x(t)$ would be defined on $t<1/x_0$. Remember that solutions of differential equations are defined on intervals only.

Comment: @Did: I didn't say it would be undefined, yes it would be defined on $t < 1/x_0$, and it's always positive and approaches to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow 1/x_0$ from the left. But I still don't see how to proceed further from here. Your vague hints are annoying:P

Comment: @Evgeny: can you kindly help me with this problem?

Comment: I can only give hints because I'm too lazy to write a full answer (and it's usually doesn't really worth it). I suggest you to review the definitions of invariant manifolds in your book. You're luck that in this case your equations are decoupled and you can solve them and explicitly find stable/unstable/center manifolds.

Comment: @Evgeny: I solved for the general solution in the comment above. But please keep in mind that $(0,0,0)$ is not hyperbolic, so I can't use theorems to find stable/unstable/center manifolds. Can you please be more patient about finding stale/unstable/center manifolds in this case? I looked at your comments above, but I thought the manifolds only tangent to their respective eigenspace IFF the equilibrium is hyperbolic? Of course I can find eigenspace for the linearized system, but then it's USELESS as $(0,0,0)$ is non-hyperbolic.

Comment: No, you've kinda messed it up, especially "IFF" part. Hyperbolic equilibrium has only stable and unstable manifold. If both are present, then it is an equilibrium of saddle type; in other cases it would be Lyapunov asymptotically stable or completely unstable. If equilibrium has eigenvalues on imaginary axis, then it is non-hyperbolic and thus also has center manifold (in addition to stable and unstable!). If you have only center+stable or center+unstable manifolds, then stability depends on what happens on center manifold. So you can use all the theorems you know.

Comment: @Evgeny: Okay, so for this problem, the hard way is to find the center manifold $z = c(x,y)= ax^2 + bxy+ cy^2$, then check for the sign of the coefficient $a$ or $c$, whichever is different from $0$. I think there must be an easier way? About your comment on non-hyperbolic: it is weird that you said I can use all the theorems I know, as those require the condition that the equilibrium is hyperbolic to be applicable. So, let me give it a try: by using Principal of Linearized stability, $Df((0,0,0))$ would have 3 eigenvalues: $0$ and $\pm 1$. Thus, it's unstable in the LINEARIZED one.

Comment: @Evgeny: The eigenspaces correspond to the 3 eigenvalues for the Linearized system are: center subspace $= x$-axis, unstable eigenspace $= z$-axis, stable eigenspace $= y$-axis. So the global stable and unstable/center manifolds are tangent to these stable/unstable eigenspaces at the corresponding equilibrium point. Is this solution correct?

Comment: 1) Okay, not *all* theorems :) but stable and unstable manifolds do exist for non-hyperbolic equilibria too, though it requires a bit more work to prove this (as far as I remember). 2) Remember that in your case all three equations are decoupled from each other. Because of that, coordinate axes not only correspond to eigenspaces, but they are invariant manifolds themselves.

Comment: @user177196 Flagged "annoying" comment.

Comment: @Did: whatever:( I'm tired of having to follow-up with you questions by questions, even though some of which are trivial to answer.

Comment: @user177196 Right, trying to lead you to actually think and to make mathematics is inexcusable (or, in your parlance, *annoying*).

Comment: @Did: I answered EVERY of your questions, but in this case, I don't see how it leads to anything. Is that a problem to you, if you don't want to help any further?

Comment: @Evgeny: Actually, every stable/unstable manifolds of a hyperbolic equilibrium are LOCALLY invariant. So you meant my approach above is false? I find this link which has a very useful theorem that indicates my approach above WORKS!! (see page 2: http://web.stanford.edu/~hmabuchi/AP217-2010/Tue-5-25.pdf)

Comment: How do you know I did not want to help further? Because you decided that my hints were leading nowhere (although they already helped to dispel some serious misconceptions in your mind, it seems) and found very important to say so? Now, of course, we have a different problem, which is that one cannot insult people and expect them *to continue to help*, can one?

Comment: I have said nothing about your approach. I just meant that after you've reviewed correct definition of invariant manifold, you might take a careful look at the equations you've solved and simplify calculations. I wanted to suggest you easier way, but okay, go on with that.

Comment: @Did: I didn't insult you, but if you find it that way, I apologize for coming across like that. It's up to you not to help further, although I appreciated things you had done so far for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Evgeny: based on your hint, I can rewrite the result as the following: $y(t) = c_2e^{(1/x_t)-c_1)}$, $z(t) = c_3e^{(-1/x_t) - c_1}$. So, as $x(t)$ goes to $0$ as $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$, $(y(t), z(t))$ goes to $(0, 0)$ for any $c_2, c_3$. Hmm... This implies $(0,0)$ is both stable and unstable, which doesn't make sense to me.